# How to make multiple save methods in spring data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I had a slow performance of default save method in spring data jpa. So, i decided to make save method work asynchronously cause i did not need response in this specific method.

```
@Repository
public interface WorkplaceRepo extends JpaRepository<Workplace, Long> {
    @Async
    public <S extends Workplace> S save(S workplaceE);
```

It caused the problem that all save methods in whole project started to call this asynchronous method. The question is: how to use both save methods without losing one of them(default version and async version)

i thought to create custom insert method using native query, but the entity have so many columns and foreign keys, and i am not sure that it would work correctly.

Comment: Better: introduce a (async, `@Service`) "facade", which (wires and) calls (regular) `save()`, and use that facade (instead of Repo), where needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating new repository `WorkplaceRepoAsync` with one save method something like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface WorkplaceRepoAsync extends Repository<Workplace, Long> {
    @Async
    public <S extends Workplace> S save(S workplaceE);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Much better solution will be create `WorkplaceService` with `@Async` logic method

```java
@Repository
public interface WorkplaceRepo extends JPARepository<Workplace, Long> {}
```

```java
@Service
public class WorkplaceService {
    
    @Inject
    private WorkplaceRepo workspaceRepo;

    @Async
    public Workspace saveAsync(Workspace workspace) {
        workspaceRepo.save(workplace);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following code to have both methods available:

```
@Repository
public interface WorkplaceRepo extends JpaRepository<Workplace, Long> {
      @Async
      default <S extends Workplace> S saveAsync(S workplaceE) {
         return this.save(workplaceE);
      }
}
```

This way the inherited `not async` method `save(S entity)` from `JpaRepository` would still be available to be called from your `WorkplaceRepo`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who faced same issue i would recommend to read this article. It gave good understanding of how spring data works inside, and solution of my problem.
https://medium.com/@sridharmcakec/refactor-jpa-save-method-to-improve-application-performance-b7a77db2794c

My solution:

```
public interface CustomWorkplaceRepo {
    void saveAsync (Workplace workplace);
}
```

Then I implemented CustomWorkplaceRepo

```
public class CustomWorkplaceRepoImpl implements CustomWorkplaceRepo {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Async
    @Transactional
    public void saveAsync(Workplace workplace) {
        entityManager.persist(workplace);
    }
}
```

The last step was adding to extends new interface in my old Repo

```
public interface WorkplaceRepo extends JpaRepository<Workplace, Long>, CustomWorkplaceRepo {
```

That's it. Now, in service when I want to save Workplace Entity it is possible to call "saveAsync" method